# set two parameters in a query builder symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to set two parameters `$type` and `$superior` in my query builder

```
$qb->select('a')
     ->from('xxxBundle:entity', 'a')
     ->where('a.typepro = :type')
     ->andwhere('a.superior=: superior')
     ->setParameter('type', $type)
     ->setParameter ('superior',$superior);
```

but I failed to get an appropriate result and I get the following exception :

> Invalid parameter format, : given, but : or ? expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space between ':' and your parameter name:

```
->andwhere('a.superior=: superior')
```

Instead, it should be:

```
->andwhere('a.superior = :superior')
```