# Symfony Invalid parameter format, : given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need create multiply search by years. From request  I get string like `2017,2018` and then I want get `Questions` which `createdAt`, between from start year and end year. I have query builder with part, and I'am not understand why I have this error

```
        if ($paramFetcher->get('years')) {

        $orXSearch = $qb->expr()->orX();
        $yearData = trim($paramFetcher->get('years'));
        foreach (explode(',', $yearData) as $key => $id) {
            if (!$id) {
                continue;
            }

            $orXSearch
                ->add($qb->expr()->between('q.createdAt', ':'.$key.'dateFrom', ':'.$key.'dateTo'));

            $date = $this->additionalFunction->validateDateTime($id, 'Y');
            $first = clone $date;
            $first->setDate($date->format('Y'), 1, 1);
            $first->setTime(0, 0, 0);
            $last = clone $date;
            $last->setDate($date->format('Y'), 12, 31);
            $last->setTime(23, 59   , 59);

            $qb
                ->setParameter($key.'dateFrom', $first->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->setParameter($key.'dateTo', $last->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }
        $qb->andWhere($orXSearch);
    }
```

error:

```
symfony Invalid parameter format, : given, but :<name> or ?<num> expected.
```

Comment: What if you avoid to concat string within the DQL? So, after your `if(!$id)`, add `$cParamA=':'.$key.'dateFrom'; $cParamB=':'.$key.'dateTo';` and then use `$cParamA` and `$cParamB` in your DQL. You would most likely need two other variable for the `seParameter`. Also, make sure to trim `$key` just in case

Comment: `SELECT q FROM AppBundle:Questions q WHERE (q.createdAt BETWEEN :0dateFrom AND :0dateTo) OR (q.createdAt BETWEEN :1dateFrom AND :1dateTo) ORDER BY q.createdAt ASC`
and I checked `parameters`, everything is in place

Comment: I changed query to 
`$orXSearch
                    ->add($qb->expr()->between(
                        'q.createdAt',
                        $qb->expr()->literal($first->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                        $qb->expr()->literal($last->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
                    );`
but I think this is bad way, I want use parameters

Comment: yes, you should use parameters indeed... But I can't guess where your query is wrong... :/

Comment: I found another solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445652/set-two-parameters-in-a-query-builder-symfony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop, you’re looping over the result of an `explode` operation which yields a numeric array, i.e. `$key` will always have a numeric value.

Hence, your parameter placeholder is colon + number + string, i.e. `:1dateFrom`. This is not allowed. Either you reference a string value with a colon + string placeholder (`:foo`), or you reference a numeric value with a question mark + number value (`?1`).

Your problem is easy to solve: Simply add any letter between the colon and the number, and you’re good:

```
->add($qb->expr()->between(
    'q.createdAt',
    ':x'.$key.'dateFrom',
    ':x'.$key.'dateTo'
));
```

Comment: Just lost couple of hours because of this, I did :1filter, :2filter, instead of :filter1, :filter2 as param name. Thanks for saving my laptop that I was about to throw out the window.